# Rails 5 Assets not compiling images or css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, assets

I would appreciate any help great. I recently updated my app to rails 5.2.3 (from 4.0.1) and noticed that when I added a new image to assets/images it failed to display in production. I ended up running rake assets:clobber and tried to rebuild my assets with rake assets:precompile. Unfortunately now all my assets are dead.

Everything works as expected in development when I start a rails server and go to localhost:3000

I have tried tinkering with the production.rb configuration file but have made no progress. Any help would be appreciated, I have put a lot of work into this website and it used for medical professionals around the world. I am not a professional programmer by any stretch. I notice that after running

```
assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

A new public/assets folder was created but only contains three files:

- .sprockets-manifest-.....json
- manifest-....js
- manifest-.....js.gz

instead of all the images i have in my assets/images folder

**production.rb**

```
BoardsApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
   config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.6.3'
gem 'rails', '5.2.3'
gem 'puma'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-switch-rails'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'pg', '0.21.0'
gem 'haml'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'rake'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'capybara'
end
  
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

**Update**
I restored the website from an earlier deployment on Heroku so at least its alive for now but I have not resolved the issue of how to update since none of my images appear to be compiling.

When I run rails server in production I get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css"):
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/application.js"):
```

whereas in development everything loads as expected.
**UPDATE**
**SOLVED!**
Thank you for the suggestion to look in the heroku logs. I found the error:

```
Asset `application.css` was not declared to be precompiled in production
```

From there I found https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/458 this discussion.

I downgraded my sprockets-rails gem to 2.3.3. and ran rake assets:precompile again and everything was in working order.

Comment: After doing that the app just crashes completely and I get the we're sorry but something went wrong page.

Comment: When you get the something went wrong page you are supposed to look in the log files to find out what exactly went wrong and then you can work on fixing that, so post the actual error you get

Comment: assets:clobber will empty out your assets folders. You will need to re-write all your css and javasscript and re-copy in your images then precompile the assets. So copy accross all the assets from the old project folder and try compiling again. Every time you add an asset and release to production you must compile

Comment: The app/assets folder still has all my image and css.scss files and js.coffee files as it always did. The app works perfectly in development. Something is going wrong in production that never used to happen before I upgraded to rails 5. For some reason rake assets:precompile doesn't seem to compile.

Comment: What err9or are you seeing when you compile the assets?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when working on a **Rails 6** application in **Ubuntu 20.04**.

The issue for me was that I was not serving the precompiled assets properly in production..

**Here's how I fixed it**:

First, I ran the command below to precompile the assets and make them available in the `public` directory of my application:

```
rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This compiles and copies images, css and js from `app/assets` and `app/javascript` to `public/`.

**Note**: In development, this can be accomplished using `webpacker` with the command: `/bin/webpack-dev-server`

Next, set up **Nginx** or **Apache** web server to serve the static files that are available in the `public` directory of my application. For me I set up **Nginx** with the configuration below using **Let's Encrypt** for SSL:

```
upstream railsserver {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {

        # Replace 'localhost' with your FQDN if you want to use
        # your app from remote or if you need to add a certificate 
        server_name my-website.com www.my-website.com;
                        
        root /home/deploy/my-website/public;

        # Define where Nginx should write its logs
        access_log /var/log/nginx/my-website/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/my-website/error.log;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # the rails application directory
            try_files $uri @railsserver;
        }
       
        location ~ ^/(assets/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
                expires max;
        }

        location @railsserver {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header CLIENT_IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                proxy_pass http://railsserver;

                gzip on;
                gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css image/svg+xml application/javas$
                gzip_proxied any;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**